# Is there a way to show the calendar on iPhone lock screen?

Tags: calendar, ios, iphone

I used to be a Windows Phone user and I loved the way the calendar (a today's agenda) is shown on the lock screen. So I was wondering if there's a way to see a days's events on the iPhone lock screen. It happens that I feel I am out of sync with day's events without having it on my lock screen.

Comment: As a wallpaper or background? No - otherwise see tetsujins answer

Answer (score 5):

Swipe down the screen from the top, it will show events you have set to show at the lock-screen.

You can decide what to show in Settings > Notifications
& whether to allow it at all in Settings > TouchID & Passcode

Comment: I dont want it to swipe down I just want them to be shown without pulling down..

Comment: @uDaY Not possible (without jailbreaking)

Answer (score 1):

Not without jailbreaking, the notification centre is currently the only place where widgets can be displayed in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a screen capture of your calendar and then use the image as your lock screen

Comment: not very practical, showing a outdated calendar.

Comment: Well, you could make a new one every day...

Comment: This actually is really helpful for many people. There's even software to automate this on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

"Lock Info" on the app store can do this. Works pretty well but not as good as some of the jailbroken alternatives.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lock-info-lock-screen-reminders/id683108563?mt=8

Comment: I can't find any decent jailbrocken alternative. Would you mind sharing a name?

Answer (score 0):

[Lock Screen Calendar](https://appsto.re/us/E6z9I.i) is supposed to do the trick

Answer (score -1):

You can simply swipe left from the Home screen to see all Calendar, Reminders, Travel, News, Weather, and much more!